# How can I draw things in the foreground with pygame?

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

How can I draw things in the foreground with pygame? With things I mean a text that I draw with .blit. Because I have a floor that hides the text I want to show How could I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) draw one image onto another. Therefore you must draw the text after the floor:

```py
screen.blit(floor, floor_pos)
screen.blit(text, text_pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you draw the foreground, then the text.